# Form validation only showing first error message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am validating a form and I can display only the first error message:

```
ContactUs.prototype.desktopErrors = function(){
    var THIS = this;

    THIS.$el.find('#submit').on('click', function(){
            if (!$('#firstName').val().length) {
                $('.nameErrs li').text("We can't verify your name")
            } else if (!$('#lastName').val().length) {
                $('.nameErrs li').text("We can't verify your last name")
            } else if (!$('#emailAddress').val().length) {
                $('.emailErrs li').text("We can't verify your email address")
            } else if (!$('#lastName').val().length) {
                $('.emailErrs li').text("We can't verify the subject")
            }
        });

    return THIS;
};
```

this is JADE:

```
    .row
        .form-group
            label.first_name_label(for="firstName") First Name*
            input.first_name_input(required type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName")

        .form-group
            label.last_name_label(for="lastName") Last Name*
            input.last_name_input(required type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName")

        ul.nameErrs
            li.full

    .row
        .form-group
            label.email_address_label(for="emailAddress") Email Address*
            input.email_address_input(required type="email" class="form-control" id="emailAddress")

        .form-group
            label.(for="subject") Subject*
            input.(required type="text" class="form-control" id="subject")

        ul.emailErrs
            li.full
```

So, if all of the fields are empty, the I am unable to display all the error messages, only the first one.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

`if else` is a fail fast logical construct

you need to use just `if blocks` for all the fields

```
THIS.$el.find('#submit').on('click', function(){
    if (!$('#firstName').val().length) {
        $('.nameErrs li').text("We can't verify your name")
    }
    if (!$('#lastName').val().length) {
        $('.nameErrs li').text("We can't verify your last name")
    }
    if (!$('#emailAddress').val().length) {
        $('.emailErrs li').text("We can't verify your email address")
    }
    if (!$('#lastName').val().length) {
        $('.emailErrs li').text("We can't verify the subject")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect your `else if` logic. Then append text so as to not overwrite.

```
THIS.$el.find('#submit').on('click', function(){
    $('.nameErrs li').text("");
    $('.emailErrs li').text("");

    if (!$('#firstName').val().length) {
        $('.nameErrs li').text("We can't verify your name")
    }
    if (!$('#lastName').val().length) {
        $('.nameErrs li').text( $('.nameErrs li').text() + "We can't verify your last name")
    }
    if (!$('#emailAddress').val().length) {
        $('.emailErrs li').text("We can't verify your email address")
    }
    // FYI: in your snippet this is a reevaluation of lastname
    if (!$('#subject').val().length) { 
        $('.emailErrs li').text( $('.emailErrs li').text() + "We can't verify the subject")
    }
});
```